# AES-256-GCM decryption in nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption

i am trying to decrypt the data stored in my database before sending it to the client side.

I am using the builtin crypto module with AES-256-GCM encryption.

I have successfully implemented the encryption and it is working properly my problem is i am trying to decrypt the data in a different file but i keep getting an error.

this is the error:

`(node:35798) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "iv" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined`

1.js

```
router.post(
"/",
async(req, res) => {

function getFullAddress({housenumber, address1, address2, city, postcode, country}) {
return [housenumber, address1, ...(address2 ? [address2]: []), city, postcode, country].join(", ");
}

const aes256gcm = (key) => {

const encrypt = (str) => {
const iv = new crypto.randomBytes(16);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);

let enc = cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'base64');
enc += cipher.final('base64');
return Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(enc), iv, cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString("base64");
};

return {
encrypt,
};
};

const aesCipher = aes256gcm(key);

const hashedPasscode = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.passcode, 12);

        await User.create({
                            email: req.body.email,
                            mobilenumber: aesCipher.encrypt(req.body.mobilenumber),
                            passcode: hashedPasscode,
                            address: aesCipher.encrypt(getFullAddress(req.body))

                          })
```

2.js

```
router.get(
"/",
async(req, res) => {

const aes256gcm = (key) => {

  const decrypt = (enc, iv, authTag) => {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
    let str = decipher.update(enc, 'base64', 'utf8');
    str += decipher.final('utf8');
    return str;
  };

  return {
    decrypt,
  };
};

const aesCipher = aes256gcm(key);

const decrypted_MobileNumber = aesCipher.decrypt(user.mobilenumber);
const decrypted_address = aesCipher.decrypt(user.address);

console.log('decrypted_MobileNumber',decrypted_MobileNumber)
console.log('decrypted_address',decrypted_address)
```

here is an example of the data stored in my database

`mobilenumber: 'Sm4xQjA2bmUwUUdEdW4zQkZ3PT3QEq5fBbTJ9ht4TgpQXTLmPYBSoQA836977j0rr3GYwg==',`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you do during encryption:

```
Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(enc), iv, cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString("base64");
```

Now, you need to reverse this during decryption:

```
enc = Buffer.from(enc, "base64");
const iv = enc.slice(enc.length-32, enc.length-16);
const tag = enc.slice(enc.length-16);
enc = enc.slice(0, enc.length-32);
```

The second issue is that a nonce/iv for GCM mode should be 12 bytes long. I've changed that and so some of the indices from the previous issue should change too.

The third issue is that you cannot concatenate encrypted and Base64-encoded chunks. You have to concatenate them before Base64 encoding so that there is no Base64 padding in the middle of the string. This shouldn't be much of an issue for GCM because the call to `cipher.final('base64');` should return an empty string.

The fourth and clear issue is that during encryption you're encoding twice, but you only need to encode once.

And together this would look like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const aes256gcm = (key) => {

  const encrypt = (str) => {
    const iv = new crypto.randomBytes(12);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);

    let enc1 = cipher.update(str, 'utf8');
    let enc2 = cipher.final();
    return Buffer.concat([enc1, enc2, iv, cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString("base64");
  };

  const decrypt = (enc) => {
    enc = Buffer.from(enc, "base64");
    const iv = enc.slice(enc.length - 28, enc.length - 16);
    const tag = enc.slice(enc.length - 16);
    enc = enc.slice(0, enc.length - 28);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
    let str = decipher.update(enc, null, 'utf8');
    str += decipher.final('utf8');
    return str;
  };

  return {
    encrypt,
    decrypt,
  };
};

const cipher = aes256gcm(Buffer.alloc(32)); // just a test key
const ct = cipher.encrypt('test');
const pt = cipher.decrypt(ct);
console.log(pt);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer will give it a try now. What was my encoding issue?

Comment: You've decoded from base64 very late and I moved that to the beginning.

Comment: oh i understand now, since i need to decode the first thing before slicing the iv and auth tag. i have tried this solution and got this error for some reason `(node:55820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data`

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time and help, really appreciate it. Can you point out where i was encoding twice? im still new to encryption thats why

Comment: During encryption `enc` is already the base64 encoded ciphertext. Then you do `Buffer.from(enc)` which uses the default utf8 decoding and not base64. Afterwards you do `toString("base64")` which is the second base64 encoding

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, i got this error `The "list[1]" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type string ('')` so i console.log enc1 and enc2, i got a buffer for enc1 and an empty string for enc2. Do i need enc2 or should i just remove it?

Comment: I haven't seen that error. What node version do you use? If the error persists, you can `enc2 = Buffer.from(cipher.final());` which should work regardless of your version. Just because it is empty now, it might not always be. The implementation of AES-GCM might change in the future which might return data from the `final` call

Comment: my node version is v12.18.1. I removed enc2 from the buffer concatenate array and it works, but will add `enc2 = Buffer.from(cipher.final());` as suggested and update you, thanks again :) Also, should i add ('base64') to it like before or do we want it as a buffer?

Comment: Strange. If it is a string, it will be converted to a Buffer with the default encoding (utf8), but if it is already a Buffer it will be simply copied.

Comment: so when enc2 is not empty this means that the encrypted messages is split across enc1 and enc2 ?

Comment: Exactly, we should not throw away values that might be non-empty when the internal implementation changes. Btw, I'm running 12.21.0 on repl.it.

Comment: Hi, i was testing the code out and the decryption was working but then now i keep getting `(node:21985) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid authentication tag length: 7` located here `decipher.setAuthTag(tag);`. so then i did `console.log(tag)` and it was `7`. How do i fix this?

Comment: Now i got another error `(node:22097) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid IV length`

Comment: Probably lost some bytes along the way. The tag is at the end, so you should check whether you read the whole ciphertext when trying to decrypt.

Comment: The IV is supposed to be 96 bit or 12 bytes, but if it makes a difference you could use 128 bit or 16 bytes. This change requires an additional step to derive the correct IV, but it happens automatically behind the scenes

Comment: So, do i change `const iv = new crypto.randomBytes(12);` to     `const iv = new crypto.randomBytes(16);`?

Comment: You could but then you'd have to change the other constants like I've shown in my second snippet. They are different in the full code.

Comment: Sorry for the many questions but how do i check whether i read the whole ciphertext when trying to decrypt? I sometimes get `Error: Invalid authentication tag length: 7` or `Error: Invalid IV length`

Comment: nevermind i was trying to decrypt the wrong data. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi- I was scanning my code through sonar scan and found a Security hotspot in both encrypt and decrypt. 
The issue stating "Make sure that encrypting data is safe here" in the both below lines, 

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.alloc(32), iv);
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', Buffer.alloc(32), iv);

How to get this address here.? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony I'm not familiar with SonarCube to suggest how it can be resolved, but I assume that this is a warning that cannot be resolved through code changes and needs to be manually ignored/accepted. There are many cryptographic primitives that can be put together to come up with a secure protocol. I can't know whether the code provided here fits your use case and I'm not sure that asking a specific question on SO along with the description of your use case would provide you with a good enough assessment of that situation that you can safely resolve the warning.